# LXDE (openbox): double click on text selects only part of word (not whole text)

Tags: debian, desktop-environment, openbox, lxde

I am using `LXDE` as my desktop environment (on Debian Wheezy). My question is related to how mouse behaves in `LXDE`, but could be general to other desktop environments.

When I double click with my mouse on any text, the whole word is selected. However, when the word contains `@`, only the first part is selected (`@` acts as word separator). I.e, when I double click on the following text, only "martin" will be selected.

```
martin@asdf.com
```

I don't know where this is configured.

Is it possible to change it, so that only white space acts as separator? I want to select the whole email address when I double click on it.

Comment: This depends on the application, not on the desktop environment. Which application(s) do you want to tune?

Comment: For example in `Terminator` and `Leafpad`

Comment: You can change this behavior for `terminator` by going to Preferences -> Profiles -> General and change the value Select-by-word characters from `-A-Za-z0-9,./?%&#:_` to `-A-Za-z0-9,./?%&#:_@` by adding an `@` to the end. I don't use Leafpad so I can't help you there. But it is a per app issue as Gilles mentioned.